# float bug in css

Tags: css

I tried to make an image float on text but its not working the text comes under the image everytime.

does the font-size has anything to do with this.

or maybe the image size is to big. 
I am lost please help me find out whats wrong.

```css
  .image flottante
     {
     float:right;
    }
```

```html
    <p><img src= "image123.jpg" class="imageflottante" alt="image aleatoire" title="my picture"/>the paragraphe goes here </p>
```

Comment: Please provide more details, code snippets, maybe a running sample for someone to help.

Comment: for helping you we must see your code

Comment: and letl us know what libery u can use(bootstrap and etc...)

Comment: @sashwat ok i am out now i will do it when i get back home

Answer (score 1):

You have an incorrect style rule. It should be something like:

```
.imageflottante
{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put an incorrect class name in css. You can set styles for the class name or the HTML element. It's like this. 
By using class name :

```
.imageflottante{
  float:left;
}
```

By using HTML element :

```
p img{
  float:left;
}
```